# TS2304 TypeScript (TS) Cannot find name

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting this error about `Cannot find name 'Record'` is that a package I need to install for this class?

> Severity   Code    Description File    Project Line    Suppression State
> Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'Record'. C:\WebProjects\ITF\node_modules\orderedmap\types\index.d.ts C:\WebProjects\ITF\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)   29  Active

[image]

```
declare class OrderedMap<T = any> {
  private constructor(content: Array<string | T>)

  get(key: string): T | undefined

  update(key: string, value: T, newKey?: string): OrderedMap<T>

  remove(key: string): OrderedMap<T>

  addToStart(key: string, value: T): OrderedMap<T>

  addToEnd(key: string, value: T): OrderedMap<T>

  addBefore(place: string, key: string, value: T): OrderedMap<T>

  forEach(fn: (key: string, value: T) => any): void

  prepend(map: MapLike<T>): OrderedMap<T>

  append(map: MapLike<T>): OrderedMap<T>

  subtract(map: MapLike<T>): OrderedMap<T>

  readonly size: number

  static from<T>(map: MapLike<T>): OrderedMap<T>
}

type MapLike<T = any> = Record<string, T> | OrderedMap<T>

export = OrderedMap
```

Comment: which version of ts are you using? You can reference this link to read more about `Record`

https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-typescript-record-type#:~:text=The%20TypeScript%20Record%20type%20has%20the%20following%20syntax%3A,with%20corresponding%20values%20of%20type%20%22%20T%20%22.?msclkid=ab6b7a52c71d11ec86e595721c5bd18d

Comment: I think its version 1.8.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record is a Utility Type which was added in 2.1

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick

So by checking your Version you might consider updating.

Comment: I upgrade to 4.6.4 and I am still getting the error, I ran `npm install -g typescript@latest`

Comment: the global version is not important if you have one locally installed in your project. check what's in your package.json and update the version there